# WP CRON on shared hosting that does not allow loopback connections?

Tags: cron, wp-cron

My hosting company infrom me that they do not allow loopback connections, which are required to run the following cron task on my server. I need to run a cron task for this plugin:

http://tribulant.com/plugins/view/1/wordpress-newsletter-plugin

```
wget -O /dev/null "http://localhost/?wpmlmethod=docron&auth=XXXXXXXX" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

They provide the following code which I have adapted for my hosting (path to wget being /usr/bin/php I blieve).

I've also tried letting wp-cron.php do the job itself, and it fails, I've also tried making a simple server cron job that manually fires wp-cron.php, this worked once and didn't fire again. I'm now testing the latter with a longer schedule.

Ahhh! Thanks.

Comment: no don't replace wget, just change localhost to your domain name and add the command to your server cron job. And it should work. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have tried the code as is, with my URL and auth code, provided by the plugin. When I test the command on my server I recieve: "Cannot find 'wget'". If I preceed wget with usr/bin/php then it gives no error.

Comment: No, wget and /usr/bin/php are two separate commands. Can you please try the command curl? if curl is there then you can curl instead of wget. Do you have shell access on your shared hosting?

Comment: I'm now trying this... /usr/bin/php curl --silent --compressed curl http://www.mydomain.co.uk/wp-cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: no no.. just run cur. don't prefix it with /usr/bin/php. And don't run wp-cron.php run the url plugin gave you. it should be: curl --silent "http://localhost/?wpmlmethod=docron&auth=XXXXXXXX"

Comment: Apoologies, I didn't mention that I've been trying to fire wp-ron through a server cron task. When I try curl without the prefix I get the "Cannot find curl" error.

Comment: @Bill: `curl` is *not* a PHP script; it is a stand-alone executable. On many systems `curl` lives in `/usr/bin/curl` and that is what you should use for the fully-qualified command path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just try the alternate WP Cron method, which doesn't require loopbacks.

Add `define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);` to your wp-config.php file.

Comment: Well, my 2 minute interval job for the plugin mentioned above is not firing using the alternate method. Is it advisible to create a server cronjob to fire wp-cron.php?

Comment: You need to understand something about wp-cron. It's not a guaranteed timing mechanism. wp-cron only ever fires based on site activity. If you have a job set to fire every two minutes, but nobody visits your site for an hour, then the job doesn't fire for an hour. wp-cron is not meant for stuff that must be done on a regular basis, and it never will be meant for that. If you have anything that *must* happen at a specific time, then don't even consider using wp-cron for it.